# UNIX sendmail alias file for non-root user

Tags: sendmail, redhat, mailx

On RedHat, I am not the admin of my server, that is, I have no access to create the /etc/mail/aliases file nor run anything as an admin.

Is it possible for me to have a local mail alias file in my home directory?  Will anything need to be done with the mail configuration file to look in one's home directory also?

Answer (score 0):

0) On many Linuxes `sendmail` uses `procmail` to deliver message to users' mailboxes.
Have you tried to use `~/.procmailrc`?
see `mail procmailex` (procmail examples)

1) Have you tries to use `~/.forward` file?
It may specify:
2a) directly specify destination address
(it would leave envelope sender address unchanged so it will hit SPF based anti-spam blocks)
2b) program to handle incoming mail e.g. procmail